# Populating Table Cells With Alamofire Data

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

For the better part of the day, I've been attempting to play with Alamofire and use it to gather some API-based data to populate a table.  I've successfully managed to get the data into my iOS app (I can println to see it), but I cannot for the life of me figure out the context to use my data to populate the correct number of table rows and set a label.

My data from the web is like so;

```
{
"members": [
    "Bob Dole",
    "Bill Clinton",
    "George Bush",
    "Richard Nixon",
    ]
}
```

My TableViewController has code like so;

```
...
var group: String?
var memberArr = [String]()
var member: [String] = []
...

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    func getData(resultHandler: (data: AnyObject?) -> ()) -> () {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://testurl/api/", parameters: ["groupname": "\(group!)"])
        .responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, _) in
            let json = JSONValue(JSON!)
            let data: AnyObject? = json
            let memberArr:[JSONValue] = json["members"].array!
            for obj in json["members"] {
                let member = obj.string!
            }
            resultHandler(data: data)
        }
    }
...



...
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return memberArr.count
}
....
```

My return memberArr.count does not work

What I cannot figure out, however, is how to get my "member" variable to be accessible throughout the controller, as I'd like to use it to return the proper number of rows or use the list of members to dynamically set the title of each cell.

I know this is a novice question, but I've dug through StackOverflow and none of the questions seem to fit in to my situation.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that getData has a completion block that run in the background, you need to tell swift to update the table after you finish reading the returned data data, but you need to send this update back in the main thread:

```
func getData(resultHandler: (data: AnyObject?) -> ()) -> () {
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://testurl/api/", parameters: ["groupname": "\(group!)"])
    .responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, _) in
        let json = JSONValue(JSON!)
        let data: AnyObject? = json
        let memberArr:[JSONValue] = json["members"].array!
        for obj in json["members"] {
            let member = obj.string!
        }
        resultHandler(data: data)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps you!

Comment: I understand now!  It took me some time to get this woking but your suggestions got me on the right path.  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry @user3163404 the answer is correct to the best of my knowledge we need to ask to ZbadhabitZ what he did different if it still not working for you.

Comment: @Icaro you are my personal savior! Thank you - your answer helped me a lot.