# Populating table view with Alamofire response

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to populate my UITableView with response that I get with Alamofire. The url for JSON is https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=a07e22bc18f5cb106bfe4cc1f83ad8ed. I just need response.result.value["results"] array of dictionaries from this JSON. 
I got it with no problem, but when I tried to print this outside of Alamofire, the request it is empty, and my cells cannot be populated with this data since number of cells is 0.
I tried tableView.reloadData() in main thread, as it is said here [Populating Table Cells With Alamofire Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676173/populating-table-cells-with-alamofire-data), but this gave no positive results. What do you think I am doing wrong? I delegated table view, and updated frames, everything should be working.

Here is the chuck of code:

```
func retrieveRecentEntries() {
    let url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=a07e22bc18f5cb106bfe4cc1f83ad8ed"

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: [:], encoding: .JSON, headers: [:]).responseJSON { (response) in
        self.entries = (response.result.value!["results"] as? [NSDictionary])!

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print("OO")
            print("Entries1: \(self.entries)")//giving JSON


            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    print("Entries2: \(self.entries)")//empty

}
```

UITableView Delegate Methods:

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //Sort entries by date and return amount of entries for each date section
    return entries.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("entryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EntryCell

    //Populate each indexPath.row with one entry
    let entryDict = entries[indexPath.row]

    let dateString = entryDict["release_date"] as! String
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    let dateDate = formatter.dateFromString(dateString)
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy"

    let dateStr = formatter.stringFromDate(dateDate!)

    //Store entry details to show them as labels
    let projectName = entryDict["title"] as! String
    let description = entryDict["overview"] as! String
    let task = entryDict["original_title"] as! String
    let hours = entryDict["vote_average"] as! Double

    //Show cell labels
    cell.projectNameLabel.text = projectName
    cell.dateLabel.text = dateStr
    cell.taskLabel.text = task
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = description
    cell.hoursLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", hours)

    print("HERE")//this isn't printed
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jack is correct that your line `print("Entries2: \(self.entries)")` is empty because it is being executed immediately after the `Alamofire` request is sent.
Putting your assignment of `self.entries` inside of your `dispatch_async` shouldn't make a difference, but it's worth a try.

You mentioned that you have correctly set your `delegate`. Have you also set your `dataSource`?

Where are you calling `retrieveRecentEntries()`?

---

#### Some Suggestions for what they're worth.

While using `NSDictionary` will work, it comes from `Objective-C.` Instead of `[NSDictionary]` I would suggest a more "Swifty" approach and using `[String : AnyObject].`

There are also a lot of instances where you are implicitly [unwrapping](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/0/12/optionals) your [optionals](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/swift-optionals-use-let/). This is alright if you *know* that the values will never be `nil.` But since the values you are unwrapping are coming from a server, it's best to handle the possibility of those values being `nil.` Because if they are and you implicitly unwrap them, your app will crash.
I would propose updating your code to make it safer and doing as follows.

```
func retrieveRecentEntries() {
    let url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=a07e22bc18f5cb106bfe4cc1f83ad8ed"

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: [:], encoding: .JSON, headers: [:]).responseJSON { (response) in

        guard let validResponse = response.result.value as? [String : AnyObject], validEntries = validResponse["results"] as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            return
        }

        // Now you can assign validEntries to self.entries because you know it is not nil
        self.entries = validEntries

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print("OO")
            print("Entries1: \(self.entries)")//giving JSON
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

I would also update all the places in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` where you're implicitly unwrapping values from `entryDict`. Anytime any of those values are nil your app will crash. If you're not already familiar with it, I would [checkout](https://thatthinginswift.com/guard-statement-swift/) Swift's `guard` [statement](http://ericcerney.com/swift-guard-statement/).

Comment: Hey, even though it didn't solve my problem, thanks for `guard`, I found it very beneficial rather than using `if ... else ...` here.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad you were able to figure your issue out. 

Answer (score 0):

When you print Entries2, the array is empty because that code is executed immediately after the alamofire request is sent, so the response hasn't been received yet.

What may be happening is that when you call reloadData(), the entries are not updated. Try moving

```
self.entries = (response.result.value!["results"] as? [NSDictionary])!
```

to inside the dispatch_async block.

Answer (score 0):

This question was all about encoding. I was encoding parameters as .JSON, which is not necessary for .GET function. It should be

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: [:], encoding: .URL, headers: [:]).responseJSON { (response) in
```

or

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: [:], headers: [:]).responseJSON { (response) in
```

as encoding with URL is default setting. The code is correct, and yes, I used `guard` to safely unwrapp received data.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, in Alamofire 3 (Swift 2.3), `response.result.value` is nil in case of failure, so you can't use this anymore:

```
guard let validResponse = response.result.value as? [String : AnyObject], validEntries = validResponse["results"] as? [String: AnyObject] else {
    return
}
```

You need to parse the data, since the data is always returned, whether the response is a success or a failure:

```
guard let data = response.data,
                    let json = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []),
                    let responseJSON = json as? [String:AnyObject] else {
    return 
}
```